# Unable to store values in a numeric array inside for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to store values into a numeric array using a sliding window. However, I am not able to store values using the following code -

```
d=c(1:1000)
e=0
for (i in d){
a[e]=c(i:i+10)
e=e+1
}
```

I am looking to see -

```
a[1]=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
a[2]=2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Comment: Are `a[1]` and `a[2]` supposed to be the same? I'm not seeing the difference...

Comment: Sorry, made the correction!

Comment: Won't it be `a[e]=c(i:i+9)`?

Comment: Umm...I am not too sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a list:

```
first <- c(0:9)
a <-lapply(1:1000, function(x) first+x)
```

> a[1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
>
> a[2]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
>
> a[3]   3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

Answer (score 2):

You might use `embed` and then `apply` to reverse each row

```
x <- 1:20
t(apply(embed(x, 10), 1, rev))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
# [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11
# [3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11    12
# [4,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12    13
# [5,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13    14
# [6,]    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14    15
# [7,]    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15    16
# [8,]    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16    17
# [9,]    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17    18
#[10,]   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18    19
#[11,]   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19    20
```

---

This might be a faster option of the same idea

```
out <- embed(x, 10)
out[, ncol(out):1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be an array? The following makes a matrix:

```
sapply(1:10, function(i) i:(i+10))
```

This may work depending on the downstream application. If it has to be an array, check out [How to convert matrix into array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572656/how-to-convert-matrix-into-array)

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
 [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11
 [3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11    12
 [4,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12    13
 [5,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13    14
 [6,]    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14    15
 [7,]    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15    16
 [8,]    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16    17
 [9,]    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17    18
[10,]   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18    19
[11,]   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19    20
```